How to declare a generic object type sent as a parameter to a widget?
I am creating a generic widget within which I want to display the SearchField widget each time with a different return value.For example:
SearchField<String>
SearchField<CustomObject>

When every time I want to send the value of this object and display it as a return value (so that I can use it generically),
For example:
SearchField<customObjectType>.
How can I declare the customObjectType in the widget?

Dart supports using generics.
Here, we use T as the type - as it serves as a placeholder for a type that will be specified later.
class SearchField<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(T) onSearch;

  const SearchField({
    Key? key,
    required this.onSearch,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onSubmitted: (String value) {
        onSearch(value as T);
      },
    );
  }
}



It's not clear what you aims to achieve, but here's a parametrized generic widget:
class SearchField<T> extends StatelessWidget{
  final T genericObject;

  const SearchField({super.key, required this.genericObject});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // do whatever you want with the genericObject
  }
}

